# Replicate aws cloudsearch data into apache solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, amazon-cloudsearch, file-search

Is there any way to replicate replicate file index data which is aws cloudsearch to apache solr hosted on ec2 real time.

Answer (score 0):

Not really- in order to make sure that all of your original documents are indexed correctly you have to reindex them into Solr in their original form.

Comment: There's no way to copy the raw index files from CloudSearch? (Actually all the Lucene files) (Edit: it doesn't make sense in real time though)

Comment: @GaëlJ  this requirement is momentary. migrating from hosted ec2 solr to managed Cloud Search service. so requirement to have hosted ec2 has fall back only for two to three weeks untill system stabilize